# Why does my horizontal scrollbar deactivate after use of columnconfigure

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I am creating a GUI in Python 3 on a Windows 8 computer. The GUI is to have a horizontal and vertical scrollbar surrounding a canvas, all of which resides in a frame. I would like to have the contents of my inner frame resize (expand or contract horizontally) when the window size changes.

Problem: Either I have a working horizontal scrollbar, or the contents of my inner frame can resize. I can't seem to get both to work.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
import subprocess
import datetime
import os

# Vertical padding for all objects, and Horizontal padding for all objects (if ever used).
v_pad, h_pad = 2, 2
# Set the 'x' and 'y' location of the top left corner of the GUI.
x, y = 0, 0
w, h = 500, 500

class Application(Frame):

    # Initialize the Frame
    def __init__(self, master):
    # Method to get canvas and contents to resize properly
        def onCanvasConfigure(self):
            [ts_frame.columnconfigure(x, minsize="3cm", weight=1) for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
            c1.itemconfigure("innerFrame", width=c1.winfo_width())
            c1.configure(scrollregion=c1.bbox("all"))
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        nbook = ttk.Notebook(root)
        nbook.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
        f1 = ttk.Frame(nbook)
        c1 = Canvas(f1, bg='green', bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        ts_frame = ttk.Frame(c1)
        vsbar1 = Scrollbar(f1, orient="vertical", command=c1.yview)
        hsbar1 = Scrollbar(f1, orient="horizontal", command=c1.xview)
        vsbar1.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        hsbar1.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
        c1.config(yscrollcommand=vsbar1.set, xscrollcommand=hsbar1.set)
        c1.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        c1.create_window(0, 0, window=ts_frame, anchor="nw", tags=("innerFrame",))
        #c1.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: c1.configure(scrollregion=c1.bbox("all")), [ts_frame.columnconfigure(x, minsize="2cm", weight=1) for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
        c1.bind("<Configure>", onCanvasConfigure)
        self.ts_tab(ts_frame)

        nbook.add(f1, text='Time Stamp Check')


# Start ts_tab
    def ts_tab(self, tab_loc):

        # Set up file name entry.
        Label(tab_loc, text="Select file:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.flnm1 = ttk.Entry(tab_loc)
        self.flnm1.focus_set()
        self.flnm1.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=4, sticky=EW)
        ttk.Button(tab_loc, text="Browse...", width=10, command=lambda: self.browse(self.flnm1)).\
                grid(row=0, column=5)

    def browse(self, target):
        temp = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        target.delete(0, END)
        target.insert(0, temp)

root = Tk()

root.iconbitmap("gws_logo_new.png")

# Create the menu bar
menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label='Open')
filemenu.add_command(label='Save As')
filemenu.add_command(label='Quit', command=root.quit)
helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)

helpmenu.add_command(label='Read Me')
# put the 'File' and 'Help' dropdown menus into the menubar.
menubar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=filemenu)
menubar.add_cascade(label='Help', menu=helpmenu)
root.config(menu=menubar)

root.geometry("%ix%i+%i+%i" % (w, h, x, y))

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

I believe the problem has to deal with my method `onCanvasConfigure`

```
# Method to get canvas and contents to resize properly
        def onCanvasConfigure(self):
            [ts_frame.columnconfigure(x, minsize="3cm", weight=1) for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
            c1.itemconfigure("innerFrame", width=c1.winfo_width())
            c1.configure(scrollregion=c1.bbox("all"))
```

, which performs a `columnconfigure` on my inner frame `ts_frame`. Without the `columnconfigure`, the horizontal scrollbar works correctly but there is no resize of the `ts_frame` contents.

What do I need to do in order to have both?

**EDIT - Answer per Bryan Oakley**

Modify method `onCanvasConfigure` to the following

```
    def onCanvasConfigure(event):
        wdth = max(event.width, ts_frame.winfo_reqwidth())
        hght = max(event.height, ts_frame.winfo_reqheight())
        c1.itemconfigure("innerFrame", width=wdth, height=hght)
        c1.configure(scrollregion=c1.bbox("all"))
        [ts_frame.columnconfigure(x, minsize="3cm", weight=1) for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

With this modification, the scrollbar works and the innerframe and the entry box expand/contract when the window is resized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the inner frame to grow and shrink with the canvas, you can use the canvas `itemconfigure` command to set its actual width and height.

To get the scrollbars to work *and* the frame to resize, you have to determine the size that the frame wants to be, determine the size of the canvas, and then configure the frame to have the larger value in width and in height. You can get the requested width and height of the frame with `winfo_reqwidth` and `winfo_reqheight`.

Here is an example:

```
def onCanvasConfigure(event):
    width = max(event.width, ts_frame.winfo_reqwidth())
    height = max(event.height, ts_frame.winfo_reqheight())
    c1.itemconfigure("innerFrame", width=width, height=height)
    c1.configure(scrollregion=c1.bbox("all"))
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. 
Thank you very much, Bryan.